# Using "Oldtimer" for items?

Tags: word-usage, ambiguity

Can I use *oldtimer* for a place or an item that people get used to using during certain times?

For example:

> That photo booth has become an oldtimer for the fair goers.

Comment: You might consider "*a fixture*", or, for larger, more broad-reaching things, "*an institution*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not immediately clear to me what you would mean by calling a thing an "oldtimer" like that; my first thought on reading the sentence is that it's probably dilapidated or decrepit, and is something they're not interested in anymore because it's too old and boring.

Based on your introductory sentence, I think that [*tradition*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tradition) might suit your purposes better:

> a way of thinking, behaving, or doing something that has been used by the people in a particular group, family, society, etc., for a long time

Answer (score 0):

You probably Shouldn't, but then English is a live language.  I'm guessing that

"That photo booth has become an oldtimer for the fair goers."

Is part of a somewhat folksy reminisence, if so, go for it!

Hope this helps

dmk